# ArcMap Georefencing - sheet/image problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, query

I have a problem and I wanted to know if anyone else had experienced this. I think it is some type of bug as it doesn't occur all the time.

The problem is when I am georeferencing some 'tiff' images, when I zoom in to the image Arcmap seems to rotate the image without my consent. Even when the image has actually been georeferenced if I zoom in it will sort of flip the image, but if I zoom out of scale it will go back to the desired location.

Comment: Did you "Update Georeferencing" after referencing the image?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found the cause of the problem.

It seems if I rotate an image using windows photo viewer prior to bringing it into ArcMap and georeferencing it, this will cause the problem (for me at least!)